# How to open my app documents directory with Android File Manager

Tags: android, select, getjson, file-manager, getfiles

I've been trying to figure out a way to open the Android File Manager directly in my app's Documents directory so the user can select a JSON file among several without requiring the user to go search for the file path /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.app/files/Documents/.  So far, I can make the "go find it yourself" tactic work, but not the "take the user to the directory for them" approach.  Here's what I've tried:

```
// this is the "go find it yourself" approach that I've used:
String filename = this.getResources().getString(R.string.ExportImportFileNameString);
File directory = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
Uri dirPathUri = Uri.fromFile(directory);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.setType("*/*");
Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open in...");
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, directory);
startActivityForResult(intent, IMPORT_REQUEST);
```

When my onActivityComplete handler is called for IMPORT_REQUEST I see the returned data looks like dat=content://com.lge.filemanager.FileProvider/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.app/files/Documents/SelectedFile.json flg=0x1 }

I've tried to invoke two different combinations of intent.setDataAndType instead of intent.setTypefollowing and that fails to let me select anything:

```
// This setDataAndType setup does not allow the user to open File Manager, nor navigate to the app Documents:
intent.setDataAndType(dirPath2, "application/json");
// This allows opening of File Manager but returns immediately without allowing the user to select a file, and returns a null data pointer:
intent.setDataAndType(dirPath2, "*/*");
```

Note that I've tried creating the intent object with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, ACTION_GET_CONTENT, and ACTION_VIEW with the similar result.
If I only have one file, I know I can have the app simply open a stream reader for a known file name as such:

```
File directory = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
File importFile = new File(directory, filename);
try
{
   fis = new FileInputStream (importFile);
   InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =
           new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   ...
```

However, that doesn't allow me the flexibility that I desire to allow a user to select from multiple files. Can anyone illuminate what's going on here and how to correct the situation.

Comment: `ile directory = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` That is not the public Documents directory.

Comment: `intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, directory)` As the name suggest you should put an Uri instance there. Not a File instance.

Comment: `I see the returned data looks like dat=content://com.lge.filemanager.FileProvider/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.app/files/Documents/SelectedFile.json` Never saw that provider. But... What is your problem with it? From private location?

Comment: "open the Android File Manager" -- there is no single "Android File Manager". To the extent that there is one, it will not have access to an app's private portion of internal storage on Android 11+ devices. You will need to create your own UI for this, using the `File` `listFiles()` API to get a list of files in your desired directory.

Comment: EXTRA_INITIAL_URI should be used with an uri you obtained earlier with the same action.

Comment: @blackapps I obfuscated my app name  The point of the data was that, when i go looking for the file of interest with the first code snippet it returns with this path.  I can get to the data just fine.  But taking the user to the app Documents directory is my goal.  I  changed the EXTRA_INITIAL_URI as you suggested and that still has the same effect.

Comment: Obfuscating your apps name,? How can your fileprovider content scheme be selected by action get content? Pretty unclear what you are doing.

Comment: Initial uri is useless with action get content. Use open document instead.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so something like the following gives me a null "paths" pointer:  'File f = new File(dirPathUri.toString()); File[] paths = f.listFiles();'  I'm guessing I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Use `directory`. It contains a directory.

Comment: @blackapps I simply edited the string that you see.  Be assured, it's the right appname in my code.  I'm just (hmmm) funny like that.   ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT gives me the same behavior as ACTION_GET_CONTENT.  All I can seem to have access to in this configuration is another JSON I have in the Download folder.

Comment: @CommonsWare ah, I see, I already have the File object named directory, just use it: directory.listFiles();  Then display everything in a list in my app so the user can select whichever one he wants!  I think I get it now.

Comment: There is no reason to mess around with app names in a content scheme. You only produce confusion. You do it wrong with action open document if initial uri has no effect.

Comment: @blackapps how about when I don't want to be mentioning either a client's name or the product name in stack overflow.  Why would you need to know that when discussing a technical detail in this forum?

Comment: If you use action get content you can pick a file from primary or secundary partition. There will be no clients name or product name in it as it is all android authorities. Always the same like: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/.... So where you got one from with .FileProvider in it... or a clients name.. And what you are doing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Commonsware feedback, here's what I have for the solution to this question:

```
//--------------
// Get the documents location for this app
File directory = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
File desiredFilePath = new File(directory.toString());

try{
    // read all pathnames for files and directory
    File[] allFilesInDirectory = desiredFilePath.listFiles();

    // prepare array to place all path strings into
    ArrayList<String> filesInDirectoryArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    // retrieve each pathname file array
    // but someone could simply use the "path" object instead
    for(File path:allFilesInDirectory){
        if (path != null){
            // put all file paths into string array
            filesInDirectoryArray.add(path.getPath());
            // could discriminate based on file extension, if so desired
        }
    }

    // send file path array for processing
    ProcessDocuments(filesInDirectoryArray);
}catch(SecurityException  e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @abdo Salm, you'll have to be more clear as to what is not clear about this solution.  The solution simply retrieves the "Documents" directory for the app, then executes the "listFiles(); function that returns a list of file paths for each file in the directory.  Those first 3 lines are the solution.  The rest of the code shows how the results of that call were parsed to extract the full paths for each file in the app's "Documents" directory.